# Show commands used thru ffmpeg when video was encoded?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some videos I am trying to remember what CRF value I used to encode them.  I thought thru mediainfo I've seen screen shots from others where there is a value that shows the commands used to make the encode but not seeing that on mine.  Is there a way to see this?